# Google Play: Reasons for "Application does not provide a Wear OS application as shown/described on the store listing"?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, wear-os

So, I have been releasing Android and Wear OS apps for some time.

Since about a week, however, new Wear OS apps get rejected with the given reason: "Your application does not provide a Wear OS application as shown/described on the store listing."

There is of course a Wear OS bundle/apk in the Wear OS release track and it also works on real devices as well as on various emulators.

I double checked the usual stuff like the manifest file which does include:

After <manifest>:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />`

And after application:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.wearable"android:required="true" />
```

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"android:value="true" />
```

In the build gradle I also included:

`implementation "androidx.wear:wear:$wear_version"`

I have experimented with several different configurations, tried creating a joint release with mobile and Wear OS apk together (which doesn't work anymore) but I really couldn't figure out what the issue might be.

Oh, and I appealed rejections to Google Play and asked for more info regarding the rejections, but I didn't really get any new input.

Anyone facing similar issues?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: I get the same error, but I don't know how to correct it, do you have a solution?